# What's the difference between Vuetify card and sheet?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

Vuetify [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sheets#sheet) define the `sheet` as follows:

> The `v-sheet` is designed to power other paper components within Vuetify. It is meant to be used as a low level component.

`card` according to [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards#card) is this:

> The `v-card` component is a versatile component that can be used for anything from a panel to a static image.

To me (not `JS` person) they seem very similar. Are they interchangeable? When to use one but not the other? Can you illustrate with examples?

Comment: the docs have examples, why don't those examples suffice?

Comment: @depperm Well, if in the `v-sheet` example (on codepen) I replace all `v-sheet` tags to the `v-card` - I don't see much of a difference.

Comment: When I right-click on a `v-card` and inspect it, it uses a `v-sheet` internally, so it's not surprising that you'd get similar results. As the docs say, it's a "low-level component" - in other words, it's mostly used to make *other* components.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks, this is what I assumed. The confusing part was  `..power other paper components..`. Vuetify docs do not declare what `paper components` are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question to me sounds little bit like "What is a difference between html `div` and `section` tags?"

Do you get me? I it is semantic thing.

"Low level" components tells me that you can use `v-sheet` in `v-card` but you shouldn't do the opposite.

Like putting `span` in `p` is ok, but doing the other way is a wrong practice.

Hope that helps you ;-)

Comment: While your interpretation of "low level" may or may not be right in this case, the much more tangible technical aspects of what this means are treated below by @Steven Spungin.

Answer (score 8):

`v-card` has `slots` for title, subtitle, text, and actions.

`v-card` uses `v-sheet` and adds these areas.

If you do not need those areas, use v-sheet, as v-card adds extra overhead with extra HTML content and CSS styling.

Comment: Most precise and technical complete explanation

Answer (score 6):

`VSheet` and `VCard` will look quite similar and is quite similar because like most other component from vuetify `VCard` is made from the `VSheet` base.

A good use case for using `VSheet` is for creating your own custom component. Say you not happy with the look and feel of `VCard` and you want to create your own variant you would use `VSheet` as your base.